# Add an Excel column from lookup using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

As shown in the picture, I have an Excel file showing some products prices in local currency, and a file showing exchange rates.

An extra column is wanted to show their USD values.

[image]

Here’s how I do:

```
import xlwt, xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy 


exchange_rate = {"China": 0.16,
"Sweden": 0.13,
"Russia": 0.015}

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Price.xlsx")
old_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

wb = copy(workbook) 
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) 

for row_index in range(1, old_sheet.nrows):

    Column_B = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value
    Column_C = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 2).value

    sheet.write(row_index, 3, Column_C * exchange_rate[Column_B])

sheet.write(0, 3, "Price (USD)")

wb.save("C:\\result.xls")
```

It works ok. But I am wondering what would be a better way to do?

More importantly, how can I use Pandas to perform the same?

Comment: @Elmex80s, I want a better way to do it. and the Pandas way to do it.

Comment: You don't read in the exchange rates. Why not?

Comment: @Elmex80s, that's a good idea. how about the Pandas way?

Comment: I would ask a different question: why use Excel at all? I would do as much in Excel or I would do the opposite: as less in Excel. But not something in between I think.

Comment: @Elmex80s, there are a few hundred alike Price.xlsx so I need a quick way to process in batch.